# How do you create a bidirectional for loop in Python elegantly?

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.5, bidirectional

As in with out outer scope variables, how do you loop getting the first element forward with one var and another var for the last element backward with the same loop? Is there a function similar to enumerate that returns two vars

Comment: Why not just run two separate `for` loops, one counting up and one counting down?

Comment: Then I would not have access to both vars at the same time and it would double complexity

Comment: I can't think of a case wherein you'd *need* access to two variables that were inversely proportional to each other at the same time. But surely you could just set something like `y = -x` inside of the loop over `x`, assuming that the 'midpoint' was `0`. Then you'd have access to both at the same time, and they would be inversely proportional (with only one additional line of code).

Comment: Interesting point but how would you use a negative index, especially with a odd number of elements

Answer (score 3):

you could `zip` one iterator and its reverse:

```
z = range(20,30)

for x,y in zip(z,reversed(z)):
    print(x,y)
```

results in:

```
20 29
21 28
22 27
23 26
24 25
25 24
26 23
27 22
28 21
29 20
```

With generators, though, you have to force iteration into a `list` since `reverse` expects a sequence

```
TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence
```

`list`, `tuple` or `range` are OK.

```
g = (x for x in somefunc() if x > 0)
lst = list(g)
for x,y in zip(lst, reversed(lst)):
   ...
```

Comment: Can you show a case where a generator used properly would cause a problem in with this example

Comment: Actually it doesn't work at all with a generator unless forced into a list. I have edited my post.